# $\lim_{\overline{x} \to \infty} \left [ 1 + Ae^{-\overline{x}} + (1 - A)e^{\overline{x}}\right ] = \lim_{x \to 0}\left [ e^{x}\right] \implies A = 1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does $\lim_{\overline{x} \to \infty} \left [ 1 + Ae^{-\overline{x}} + (1 - A)e^{\overline{x}}\right ] = \lim_{x \to 0}\left [ e^{x}\right] \implies A = 1$ ?

My book says: [image]

where $$y_0 = e^{x}$$
and the notation $Y_0(\infty)$ mean $lim_{\overline{x} \to \infty}Y_0$ and $y_0(0)$ means $\lim_{x \to 0}y_0$.

How is that from the above equation of limits they deduce that $A = 1$? I get that the right hand side limit is equal to $1$, but the limit on the left goes to infinity because of the $e^{\overline{x}}$ term. Can someone please explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking limit for each term we get $1+0+\lim_{\overline x \to \infty} (1-A)e^{\overline x}=1$. So $\lim_{\overline x \to \infty} (1-A)e^{\overline x}=0$.  This also implies $\lim_{\overline x \to \infty} |1-A|e^{\overline x}=0$. If $A \neq 1$ then the limit is  $+\infty$ leading to a contradiction. Hence, $A=1$.

Comment: Why do we have the implication that you write with absolute value signs?

Comment: @ozeraozera $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ means for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $x_0$ such that $|f(x)| <\epsilon$ for all $x >x_0$. If you write this definition for $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)|=0$ you will see no difference. Hence $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} |f(x)|=0$ are one and the same.